How to plot a stacked column chart in Pine Script
I want to create a stacked area chart from CFTC COT positioning data. As best as I can tell, Pine Script does not support stacked areas. How best to accomplish this?
I faked it by plotting the "stacked" area first at full height, and then plotting the "base" area over top. That kinda works, but the stacked value displayed in the status area and Data Window is the summed value, not the incremental which is what I want.
I can address that by multiple plot() calls with various displays, but it is an imperfect solution. If the user changes the color of a plot in the settings, I have no way of knowing that, so my colors in the DataWindow/Status are wrong. If the user hides the "base" plot, then the "stacked" plot is visible full height, not incremental. If the user changes one of the plots from area to line (for example) then things start to get hidden.
You may wonder why I'm manually annotating largeTraders below. Well that's because I've left out commercials here for simplicity, so it is a bit more complicated irl. Again for simplicity, the below code ignores the fact the sign on small and large can differ.
largeTraders = getPositioning("Noncommercial Positions", cftcCode)
smallTraders = getPositioning("Nonreportable Positions", cftcCode)
stacked = smallTraders + largeTraders

// Plot the stacked columns
p1 = plot(stacked, color=color.green, title="Small Traders", style=plot.style_area, display = display.pane)
p2 = plot(largeTraders, color=color.blue, title="Large Traders", style=plot.style_area, display = display.pane)

// Plot the annotations
plot(smallTraders, color=color.green, title="Small Traders", display = display.all - display.pane, editable = false)
plot(largeTraders, color=color.blue, title="Large Traders", display = display.all - display.pane, editable = false)

